# Creating UML Class Diagrams programmatically

Tags: c#, xml, uml, class-diagram

I want to be able to create UML class diagrams programmatically, and I saw VS Ultimate Edition has UML Class diagram support which is XML internally.My question is  can I do this runtime and interactively? Meaning I have my .exe running, and I build the XML programmatically, and show the resulting diagram in a diagram component which I have placed on a Form ? Could I write code to handle dragging and resizing class shapes, creating associations and other actions associated with editing a class diagram? Or would I operate on the XML structure, and just keep the reloading the resulting diagram after each edit?

very importantly  how do I show the resulted Class Diagram ....

Answer (score 1):

Two steps:

Step 1: use DOT (graph description language) to create graph representation of class relations.

DOT is a plain text graph description language. It is a simple way of describing graphs that both humans and computer programs can use.

Step 2: Use DOT reader libraries to render as picture.

There are lot of libraries are available to render DOT file.